# Rinkeby ETH Faucet

Tags: rinkeby

Been trying to get some test ETH from the Rinkeby Faucet. I tweeted the request and when I click either 3/7.5 or 18.75 ETH I get this error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value - has anyone encountered this error?

Comment: With the Ethereum merge, Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet running. All others including Rinkeby, Ropsten, and Kovan have been deprecated.

If you need any free Goerli testETH, Alchemy has a reliable faucet - https://goerlifaucet.com. 

If you have Rinkeby, here's how to migrate over to Goerli: https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/migrate-from-rinkeby-to-goerli

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a rinkeby faucet that doesn't require social network, [this](https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby) works perfectly. It sends 0.1 ETH to your address. You can use it multiple times a day. It is also, fast.

A huge thank you to their team for providing this to the developers.

Hope this helps.